# Calculating travel time from residential points to stores via public transit using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, network-analyst

I don't know how to summarize it in just one title, but here is the problem:

My goal is to calculate the travel time from residential points to stores via public transit.  Basically this period of time consists three parts:

1. The walking time from a residential point to the nearest bus stop "t1", which can be calculated by the Nearest Facility tool from Network Analyst.  The resulting table is called "Resident_Stop", of which the number of records is m;
2. The bus-riding time "t2" from this bus stop to the nearest bus stop of the target store via bus route, which is a record from Network Analyst's OD Time Matrix table, namely, "Stop_Stop".  The origins and destinations are all bus stops on one single bus route so that the number of records is s*s;
3. The walking time from the ending bus stop to the store "t3", which is basically the same with the first step.  The table is "Stop_Store", of which the number of records is n.

So the total travel time "t" equals to (t1+t2+t3) and here is where problem occurs: I haven't figured out a way to attach the three tables reasonably to add the times on using a join.  Currently I have an OD Time Matrix table of the walking time directly from residential points to stores via road network (no transit involved) and its number of records is m*n.  I also separatly joined the table "Resident_Stop" in step 1 and the table "Stop_Store" in step 3 to the m*n-sized table based on residential point IDs and store IDs.  So the remaining thing now is to assign the bus-riding time in table 2 based on table 1's stop IDs and table 3's stop IDs to each of the m*n records.  Then I can get the total time.

Should you get any ideas, I'm willing to discuss with you.  I'm now thinking about using Python to handle this but I'm a beginner on that.  If you have any books or tutorials to recommand please tell me.

Comment: This is a big job for a beginner. Perhaps break it down into steps rather than looking at it as one big problem. So you have no trouble calculating the individual times, is that right?

Comment: Yes, all the individual tables are ready.

Comment: Is there a unique id between the 3 tables for each *trip*?

Comment: Yes.  Between 1 and 2 it is the ID of the nearest stop from the residential point.  Between 3 and 2 it is the ID of the nearest stop from the store.

Comment: Oh, there is no ID identifying each _trip_.

Comment: So how can you link 1 and 2 to its respective 3 and 2? There should be something that relates each table together. What are you trying to achieve at the end, just one trip or many trips on a table?

Comment: Many trips. I got 360 residential points and 297 stores so that's a huge number.  If there is an ID for each trip, it should be the ObjectID of the OD Time Matrix table directly from residential points to stores I mentioned in the last 2nd paragraph.

Comment: That's 106920 individual journeys. Python is capable of solving this but it's a **MASSIVE** problem to resolve each residential point to each bus stop, drive time to shop. Far too complex to be answered in one GIS.SE question. I think you need to look at the arcpy tutorials and work from there... start here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000001000000

Comment: This looks a multi-modal network analysis but as Michael said it is too broad for one GIS SE question so we will need you to work through it in a series of focussed Q&As.

Comment: Are all these tables in a database like SQLServer or Access?if yes,is it possible to make a query and join tables using common fields value?for example "select T1.t1+T2.t2+T3.t3 as TotalTime From T1 inner join T2 on T1.StopPointId=T2.StopPointId1 inner join T3 On T2.StopPointId2=T3.StopPointId

Comment: Hi @PolyGeo.  Yes, sure it is.  And I have broken it down into several smaller problems.  The only problem I cannot solve right now is finding the corresponding bus-ride record for each _trip_ based on resident's nearest bus stop ID and store's nearest bus stop ID, **automatically**.  Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Hi @Reza.  It is in geodatabase.  The ideal solution is joining these three tables together based on the starting stop ID and the ending stop ID, then I got a table of (m*n*s*s) records.  Then I can do a _Summary_ based on trip IDs to find the shortest travel time and add the three times up to have a total time for (m*n) trips.  So do you have any suggestions for joining the tables, both with or without ArcMap are OK?

Comment: If I understand problem well,maybe converting OD time matrix to a 3 columns table can be a help.using cartesian product,you can convert this matrix to s*s-s rows.each row contains 2 bus stop Ids and third column contains time.No need to those rows which both Ids are identical.Now this new table can sit between Residential_stop and stop-store tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll demonstrate my suggestion using 14 bus stops:

[image]

The trick here is to modify Stop_Stop **matrix** into shorter **table**:

[image]

The store is closest to stop 8, thus above table can be reduced to **14 rows** by Create Feature Layer (Model builder) or changing Definition Query (script) to [From_Stop]=8. 
Similar thing has to be done with stops2store table, so it will contain only 1 row:

[image]

Start your journeys by joining  house2stop, stop2stop and stop2store tables as shown below:

[image]

Add field Total to house2stop, and use field calculator to convert distance fields (last fields in above picture) to travel time. Example below shows distances only:

[image]

All this is doable using Model Builder and can be extended to the case with multiple stores, using store ID and 'Total' field name as parameters. It woul de nice though to let some of them just walk:) Note: it was tested on FGDB tables.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answers.  But one thing is that I got multiple stores and there is a chance that more than 1 stores share 1 bus stop, so problem will occur when joining Stop_Stop and Stop_Store tables.  Plus there is multiple bus routes.  Another problem I just discovered is that when using OD Time Matrix tool to generate Stop_Stop table, I always get tables with number of records less than s*s.  Do you know what may cause that?

Comment: Multiple routes is not an issue, it just make your stop_stop table longer. I hope you are not going to save travel to multiple stores in 1 field. If we can agree on this, the number of target stores is not an issue, travel times to N stores simply have to be saved in N fields. You have to iterate through stores, making one at a time THE target. Period. Without seeing your network I cannot answer s*s question.

Comment: OK, I understand you.  So for **one** bus route I can only process **one** store for all residential points with **one** operation, right?  Unfortunately I got 297 stores and 30 bus routes and that's gonna be near 9,000 operations.  Is there some methods to automate your process and iterate through stores automatically?

Comment: No, you can process one store with many routes. Important thing is to figure out what are you trying to achieve. Travel time from every house to every 297 stores? Or maybe to find the store that is fastest to reach from any house. Both actually achievable with Model Builder, but first one will add 297 fields to your houses table. Python is much better solution in any case though

Comment: Yes your table stop_stop must include all 30 routes, i.e. let them change the bus while shopping

Comment: I'm not taking bus-transferring into consideration.  It takes about 30 minutes to run 4 stores for 1 route, so it going to be more than 1 day to process 1 route and that's not acceptable.  I used Iterate Row Selection to iterate through stores, is that right?  And I used Join Field tool; it this the reason that the model runs so slowly?

Comment: The process is correct and sadly yes this is the only thing you can do with MB and yes performance of Join+calculate field is appauling. I managed to reduce comp.time upto 100 times using da module and lookup tables, but that requires scripting. However it is well outside the scope of original post, isn't it.? So mark it as answered, if you think so and seek how to accelerate calcs.